# Excel formula with two conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

One cell in each line contains a date in the format 01/01/2016. The cell next to that one contains a dollar amount.

There are from 10 to 20 lines during each month.

Each line is either no color *(ok)* or highlighted yellow *(not ok)*. I need a formula that will sum each month and return the totals for highlighted and not highlighted lines during that month.

The result should look like this:

```
                      OK              Not OK
Jan 2014            $333.00          $215.00

Feb 2014            $222.40          $610.00
```

Comment: formula can't detect formatting. Is there another way to identify them?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I know how to use Excel. I do not work with formulas often enough to even know where to start. I do have this so far:
=if(left(b2,2)="01"

Comment: Raystafarian - looks like it can detect color; I just don't know how to combine it with everything else. http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010780_Colors_in_an_IF_Function.html

Comment: @StayThirstyMyFriends - yes, it can manage colour if you use the VBA code. If you plan so then please specify it in your question, that's not a standard functionality in Excel. Please edit your question instead of answering in a comment.

Comment: No, just found it in a search. I may be in over my head here. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no formula to check on the cell "Fill color" (only on Number formats etc.) 
I suggest a far easier way : 
Add a column "HighL" in Col C where you mark HighLighted rows. 
With conditional formatting, the rows will still get your highlighted color.

Asuming your data is shaped like:

```
DATE         | Value | HighL
------------ | ----- | ----- 
01/01/2016   |     4 |  x    
01/02/2016   |    44 |   
02/02/2016   |     2 |  
02/03/2016   |     3 |  x
etc.
```

Then your summary formula would look like this:

```
DATE (mth)   |  Sum
------------ | ------
01/01/2016   | =SUMPRODUCT($B$4:$B$19*($C$4:$C$19>"")*(MONTH($A21)=MONTH($A$4:$A$19)))
02/01/2016   | =SUMPRODUCT($B$4:$B$19*($C$4:$C$19>"")*(MONTH($A22)=MONTH($A$4:$A$19)))

where 1/1/2016 is the Jan Month in  Cell A21
and the long formula is in Cell B21
```

It checks both if Column C contains a string > "" as well as if the rows summed up have the same month as in the Cell left to it (A21)

Comment: Boom! Looks like a winner. Might have addt'l question(s), but much thanks  Paschi!